# What iare sxHeight and sCapHeight in TrueType fonts?

Tags: truetype, opentype

There are 2 values in the `OS/2` table I don't understand: `sxHeight` and `sCapHeight`.
The Reference Manual says these are "The distance(s) between the baseline and the approximate height of non-ascending lowercase (uppercase) letters measured in FUnits".

What do they mean with "approximation"? The ascent and descent values are defined in the `hhea` table and also in the `OS/2` table, but both of them do not fit with this 2 values.

And what are FUnits?

```
<hhea>...
<ascent value="1040"/>
<descent value="-348"/>

<OS_2>...
<sxHeight value="287"/>
<sCapHeight value="797"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It basically means what it says: these are only "rough indicators" of the general distance between the baseline and the approximate height of non-ascending lowercase, and uppercase letters (technically: glyphs). The reason being that there are *loads* of different non-ascending lowercase letters, and *loads* of different uppercase letters, so you can't say what "the" `sxHeight` or `sCapHeight` is. There isn't one authoritative value.

However, while the *spec* makes no guarantees about their usability, *real life* is another story, as per https://typedrawers.com/discussion/3166/scapheight-and-sxheight-consistency-across-a-font-family